# SQL - Add Data to Existing Data From Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a temp table `@table` in my stored procedure that looks like this:

```
AgtID | Bonus
-------------
5063  | 0
1104  | 0
```

And a table `bonus` that looks like this:

```
AgtID | Contest | Points | Event
--------------------------------
5063  | 21      | 1000   | 1
5063  | 21      | 3000   | 3
1104  | 21      | 1000   | 1
1104  | 21      | 500    | 2
```

And an update query (currently) like thus:

```
UPDATE tt
SET Bonus = b.Points
FROM @table tt
INNER JOIN tblContestData_Bonus b
ON tt.AgtID = b.AgtID
where ContestID = 21;
```

Currently, when I run this query, it'll overwrite whatever data is in `@table.Bonus` with the data in `bonus.Points`. This is fine for a single record, but as we start getting more bonus point events, I need to have it add to my value.

I know some languages have a `i += value`... does SQL have something similar?

Comment: For a single `AgtID` you have more than one `event` so which event `points` you have to update to `@table`

Comment: I needed all of those events. The only relevant info was AgtID, Points, and then the ContestID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out right after posting. Funny how that works. What I did:

```
UPDATE tt
SET Bonus = coalesce(
        (select SUM(Points) as Points
        from bonus b
        where b.AgtID = tt.AgtID
        and ContestID = 21
        group by AgtID),0)
FROM @table tt;
```

Using the `coalesce()` to account for null values to math in following steps works fine even if there are no records.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing what you're after here, but you can add the existing value to the new value in an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE tt
SET Bonus = b.Points + Bonus
FROM @table tt
INNER JOIN tblContestData_Bonus b
ON tt.AgtID = b.AgtID
where ContestID = 21;
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this properly in SQL, you need to pre-aggregate `b`.  You cannot update a single record multiple times, so an `update` will does not accumulate when there are multiple matches.  It only updates on (arbitrary) record.

Something like this will take all the bonus points and add them in:

```
UPDATE tt
    SET Bonus = coalesce(tt.Bonus, 0) + b.Points
FROM @table tt INNER JOIN
     (select agtId, sum(points) as points
      from tblContestData_Bonus b
      group by abtId
    ) b
    ON tt.AgtID = b.AgtID
where ContestID = 21;
```